# Navigation bar is pushed down in iOS7

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am compiling my app with iOS 6.1 SDK and deploying in a iOS7 device. The app's device is set for iPhone only.

I have a view controller that I add to a navigation controller.

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                  initWithRootViewController:
                                  [[MyViewController alloc] init]];
```

When I deploy the app in iPad Mini running iOS 7, there is a strange gap shown at the top.

[image]

If I set the app's device to Universal, then the gap goes away. Is there any explanation for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The few changes which you should take care of in iOS 7:-

1) Navigation Bar of iOS 7 is of dimension :- 320 X 64 while iOS 6 it is :- 320 X 44.

2) Navigation Bar Translucent Property is YES by default in iOS 7 so set it to NO, as status bar is also included in iOS 7.

Take care of these things and it would go fine.

// Sample Code of setting the navigation controller and image programatically in iOS 7

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; 
UIImage *backgrdNavImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpg"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgrdNavImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```